# AEM 6 sightly: How to read variable from language file?

Tags: aem, sightly

I have the following html:

```
<div >${'foo' @ i18n}</div>
```

In my i18n file I have the following:

```
<foo
            jcr:mixinTypes="[sling:Message]"
            jcr:primaryType="sling:MessageEntry"
            sling:key="foo"
            sling:message="This is dummy text"/>
```

`This is dummy text` is displayed in the page. well so far. The problem is that `foo` is a variable which comes form other template and I read as follow:

```
${fooValue} //this returns foo
```

Now to read message from the i18n I tried the following:

<`div>${'${fooValue}' @ i18n} </div>`

but This displays `${fooValue}` in the page. How to read message from the `i18n`, if I have `variable key`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a local template to which you pass the variable identifying your key for the i18n dictionary:

```
<template data-sly-template.locale="${@ key}">
    ${key @ i18n, locale='de'}    
</template>

<div data-sly-call="${locale @ key='world'}"></div>
```

Assuming your i18n dictionary has the translation, the output would be:

```
<div>
    Welt    
</div>
```

You can also call the `locale` template from another template in your page:

```
<template data-sly-template.locale="${@ key}">
    ${key @ i18n, locale='de'}    
</template>

<template data-sly-template.translate="${@ string}">
    <div data-sly-call="${locale @ key=string}" data-sly-unwrap></div>
</template>

<div data-sly-call="${translate @ string='world'}"></div>
```

The output would be the same as above.

Answer (score 2):

The solution by Radu works wonderfully. I have also tried this and this works too, if anyone is looking for a solution without involving templates.

```
<div>${fooValue @ i18n}</div>
```

I personally would go with templates though. Makes it a little easier to read.
`<div>${fooValue @ i18n}</div>` vs `<div data-sly-call="${translate @ string=fooValue}"></div>`.